# WPF C# How to avoid event fire whle importing?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, import, flags

I have a WPF app with a Window and different UserControls are shown in it one by one no button clicks.

I import data from a file and all data is stored in a common object "ImportExportData". All UserControls are bind to respective Property (as custom objects like Data1, Data2...)  of ImportExportData class.

In my USerControl I have combobox's for NumberZones proeprty those SelectionChanged event is handled respectively. In the SelectionChanged event of this combobox, based on the number selected that many rows are added to an ObservableCollection of Data2 property.

While importing data and setting the imported object (Data2) as the DataContext of USerControl2, it sets the NumberZones property value to the respective combobox and SelectionChanged event is fired as it should. At this time, the object already contains reqd rows in ObservableCollection and this event should not add it.

PArent window has a flag "importedData" that tells me that the object is imported. But I can't make that false once UserContrl2 is loaded, as their are their UC that will follow UC2. In UC2 I can create another flag "importing" and make it false once all UI is loaded. Thru which UC event can I know that UI is loaded and thus make "importing" as false ??

I am wondering how do I avoid from firing the SelectionChanged event when the imported object is populating the UI components. Which event of the UserControl will help me in this case maybe to keep a flag in USerControl2.

Any idea, suggestions please.

Comment: are you using mvvm or doing things in code behind?

Comment: mvvm. Setting DataContext of the UserControl in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to understand all of your question, so bear with me... I'll address each point that I understand.

> Thru which UC event can I know that UI is loaded and thus make "importing" as false ??

Take a look at the [FrameworkElement.Loaded Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) page at MSDN.

> I am wondering how do I avoid from firing the SelectionChanged event when the imported object is populating the UI components.

There are two way of achieving this goal... The first way does not *stop* the event from firing, but instead *ignores* it when data is being imported. basically involves temporarily unsubscribing from the `SelectionChanged` event and then re-subscribing to it. If I understand you correctly, you have a `bool` property in your parent `Window` and `SelectionChanged` handlers in your `UserControl`s... first, you can add a `bool` property to each of your `UserControl`s:

```
public bool CanChangeSelection { get; set; }
```

Now, in your parent `Window` (assuming that you have references to your controls) you can update your property:

```
private bool isImporting = false;

public bool IsImporting
{
    get { return isImporting; }
    set
    {
        isImporting = value;
        UserControl1.CanChangeSelection = isImporting;
        UserControl2.CanChangeSelection = isImporting;
        ...
        UserControlN.CanChangeSelection = isImporting;
    }
}
```

Then finally, in your control `SelectionChanged` handlers:

```
private void SelectionChangedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CanChangeSelection)
    {
        // do your stuff in here
    }
}
```

The second way basically involves temporarily unsubscribing from the `SelectionChanged` event and then re-subscribing to it. For this option, we need to change the definition of our new `bool` property in each of your `UserControl`s:

```
private bool canChangeSelection = false;

public bool CanChangeSelection 
{
    get { return canChangeSelection; }
    set
    {
        canChangeSelection = value;
        if (!canChangeSelection)
        {
            if (SelectionChangedHandler != null) ComboBox1.SelectionChanged -= 
SelectionChangedHandler;
        }
        else if (SelectionChangedHandler == null) ComboBox1.SelectionChanged += 
SelectionChangedHandler;
    }
}
```

I personally prefer the first method as it is more straightforward.

Comment: Sheridan, I too had thought of Loaded event and implemented thru method "Window_Loaded" on Loaded event. But had failed to subscribe the Loaded event on the User Control. I implemented the same and it works perfectly well. Thanks a lot.